# css position: fixed gets unfixed when scrolling in chrome and safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

ok here's the problem, I'm using the `stickyjs` plugin that comes bundled with the premium `wordpress` theme. I decided to make a mobilephone image stick when it reaches the viewport top and all is working except that it gets unstuck while scrolling then moves back to its fixed position again and sometimes it flickers.
Here's the website --> http://majic.explaininja.com/

the problem occurs in chrome and safari but not in firefox

thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

When it switches from `relative` to `static`, it's using a CSS transition to go from 0px to 80px (from the top). To fix the issue, remove the transition:

```
-webkit-transition: .5s;
-moz-transition: .5s;
transition: .5s;
```

...from `#majic-process #mobile-phone`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time. Ok I removed the transitions from #majic-process #mobile-phone but the problem is still there.

Comment: It's looking great on my end in both Safari/Chrome. Which version of OS X are you using?

Comment: I'm using mountain lion. When you scroll slowly, you will notice that when it reach a certain point, the mobile phone jumps up then revert back to its fixed position.